# Keeping existing data

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I had to create another table to extract some columns
I `my_tables` there are many columns but a couple needed to be extracted to be used elsewhere.

So the `my_new_table` exists, but It doesn't have the data that I had in the columns `user`and  `guest` in `my_tables`...
So I have to rollback my migration and insert some SQL I guess? to take the data from  `my_tables` `user & guest` ? 
How to do this please ?

```
class CreateMyNewTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_new_tables do |t|
      t.string :user
      t.string :guest
      t.references :my_tables, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

      #how to keep the data I already have in Guest and User

    remove_column :my_tables, :guest
    remove_column :my_tables, :user

  end
end
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your question.

Comment: JFYI, "data" is already plural. The corresponding singular is "datum".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tables are not too big the easiest way might be to copy the data with a few lines of Ruby code within your migration. This has the benefit of using existing associations and validation and the code is easier to read and to understand for Ruby developers.

On huge tables, I would suggest doing it in plain SQL because that would be much faster.

I assume that you have both a `MyTable` and a `MyNewTable` model.

```
def up
  create_table :my_new_tables do |t|
    t.string :user
    t.string :guest
    t.references :my_tables, index: true
    t.timestamps null: false
  end

  MyNewTable.reset_column_information
  MyTable.find_each do |table|
    MyNewTable.create(user: table.user, guest: table.guest, my_table: table)
  end

  remove_column :my_tables, :guest
  remove_column :my_tables, :user
end
```

Comment: That's what I finally did thanks this was the solution :)